# What do you call a person who always provides statistics against his/her opinion?

Tags: word-request

Can you please provide the **SINGLE WORD** used to describe a person who always provides **statistics** against his/her opinion?

Comment: Someone who always argues against themself could be described as *confused*, or possibly *insane*.  Is that the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: Why do you think there should be a single word?  Is there a single word for this in your native language?

Answer (score 0):

While not specifically related to statistics, the general concept of causing problems for yourself in this way might be described using a number of terms. For example:

- Self-defeating
- Counterproductive
- Shooting yourself in the foot (slang)